# background image in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hi I have the basic boot strap layout. now on the css there is two css files
I found the one with body reference and I see that nothing else seems to be interfering with my problem

my main folder has its index.html in the root folder then I breaks as provided
img
css
js

my path for my background its simple . img/bg.jpg
so I put ../img/bg.jpg and nothing

I also tried making an images folder in the css folder and putting it there

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;

  background: url ('images/bg.jpg');

}
```

I also tried putting the link of a jpg image from google and nothing, im running the latest version, how can I achieve my goal. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS you have refers to 'images/bg.jpg' but your question refers to 'img/bg.jpg'.  Is that a typo?

Comment: no in the css i actually named it images

Comment: hey i messed up on the background

Comment: it should be background-image: im not posting in stackover until i spent a good amount of time on it sorry for wasting time